# How can I access a control that's in a grid pane?

Tags: java, loops, javafx, fxml, gridpane

I have defined a grid pane in a java fxml file as follows:

```
<GridPane fx:id="grid" gridLinesVisible="true" prefHeight="256" prefWidth="256">

  ...

  <children>
    <Label maxHeight="1.8" maxWidth="1.8" />
    <Label maxHeight="1.8" maxWidth="1.8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
    <Label maxHeight="1.8" maxWidth="1.8" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
    <Label maxHeight="1.8" maxWidth="1.8" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <Label maxHeight="1.8" maxWidth="1.8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <Label maxHeight="1.8" maxWidth="1.8" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <Label maxHeight="1.8" maxWidth="1.8" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
    <Label maxHeight="1.8" maxWidth="1.8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
    <Label maxHeight="1.8" maxWidth="1.8" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
  </children>

  ...

</GridPane>
```

The grid is 3 x 3 and has a label in each of its cells. Is it possible to loop through the grid and change the text for each label as shown in the pseudo code below:

```
for (cell : grid)
{
  cell.label.setText("x");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be

```
for ( Node node : gridPane.getChildren() )
{
    (( Label ) node).setText( "x" );
}
```

**Assuming** that `gridPane.setGridLinesVisible( false );`

However when the `gridPane.setGridLinesVisible( true )`, an additional `gridLines` (type of `Group`) is added to gridPane's children list. In this case you may to check for class types:

```
for ( Node node : gridPane.getChildren() )
{
    if(node instanceof Label)
        (( Label ) node).setText( "x" );
}
```

Note that the `gridLinesVisible` property is for debugging purposes only. There are other options to style GridPane.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without hiding the grid lines?

Comment: Hi, I've just had this issue and I can't believe that GridPanes are so picky about their lines lmao, thanks!!! Had to go back and check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892646/adding-borders-to-gridpane-javafx