# Can a Rectangle be styled to show a border?

Tags: java, javafx

The following application:

```
public class Temp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10.0,10.0);
        rect.setStyle("-fx-fill: red; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 5; -fx-border-color: black;");
        root.getChildren().add(rect);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 100, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

produces the following window:

[image]

Why doesn't my rectangle have thick black borders?

Comment: See the [CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape) (a `Rectangle` is a `Shape`). The border is called _stroke_

Comment: @Vertex Is there a way to make strokes visible only on some of the rectangle's sides and not all of them? (I guess not, since a `Shape` doesn't really know about "sides".)

Comment: No it isn't. You have to add manually lines, if you wan't that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No: [`Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#rectangle) does not support `-fx-border` etc: only [`Region`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) and subclasses do.

So try

```
public class Temp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Region rect = new Region();
        rect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 5; -fx-border-color: black; -fx-min-width: 20; -fx-min-height:20; -fx-max-width:20; -fx-max-height: 20;");
        root.getChildren().add(rect);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 100, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement your border using "nested backgrounds":

```
    rect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, red; -fx-background-insets: 0, 5; -fx-min-width: 20; -fx-min-height:20; -fx-max-width:20; -fx-max-height: 20;");
```

And you can add borders to some sides only with

```
    rect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, red; -fx-background-insets: 0, 5 5 0 0; -fx-min-width: 20; -fx-min-height:20; -fx-max-width:20; -fx-max-height: 20;");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this style instead:

```
rect.setStyle("-fx-fill: red; -fx-stroke: black; -fx-stroke-width: 5;");
```

This is all in the first section of the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).