# Get rid of separating line in gridpanes colspan in javafx

Tags: javafx, gridpane

is there any way to hide the line between columns with colspan property set in javafx gridpane ?

for example - https://i.cubeupload.com/lPKvHQ.png

Comment: The `gridLinesVisible` property is for debug purposes only...

Comment: ok ty, so how do i add table like feel to the gridpane? i.e. add lines

Comment: Put borders on the nodes in the cells. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892646/adding-borders-to-gridpane-javafx