# Label borders not lining up, not flush

Tags: java, javafx, label, border

Here is my current output in JavaFX.

I would like all of the labels and the borders to be flush.

I have all of the Insets set the same, so why is everything not aligning?

Another issue is the double overlap of borders creating a darker image on the border, I am not sure how to fix that when setting the style for my labels. Below this picture is the relevant code. Thank you.

[image]

```
    public void buildUI() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();                     // create Hbox
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,40,215) ); // centers month name over Grid
        Label month = new Label ("October");        // create october label
        //hbox.setVgap(50.0);
        this.setTop(hbox);                          // set hbox to top of borderPane
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(month);           // add month to hbox

        this.setCenter(grid);                       // add gridPane to center of BorderPane

        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20) );  // add insets to gridPane for aesthetic


          // below makes S-M-T-W-T-F and green fill
        for (int i = 0; i <= weekDays.length - 1; i++) {
            Label daysOfWeek = new Label(weekDays[i]);
            grid.add(daysOfWeek, i + 1, 1);

            daysOfWeek.setPadding(new Insets(25,30,25,30) );
            daysOfWeek.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;" +
                         "-fx-background-color: green;" + "-fx-border-color:     black;");



        }// end for loop to cycle through days of week 


        //below are the days of the month 
        for (int i = 1; i <= FRAMES; i++) {
            int yPos = ((i - 1) / 7) + 2;
            int xPos = i - (7 * (yPos -2) );

            if (i < 32) {
                Label monthDays = new Label(String.valueOf(i) );
                grid.add(monthDays, xPos, yPos);

                monthDays.setPadding(new Insets(25,30,25,30) );
                monthDays.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");




            } else if (i > 32) {
               // below creating november labels days 1 -- 4
                Label nov1 = new Label("1");
                grid.add(nov1, 4, 6);
                Label nov2 = new Label("2");
                grid.add(nov2, 5, 6);
                Label nov3 = new Label("3");
                grid.add(nov3, 6, 6);
                Label nov4 = new Label("4");
                grid.add(nov4, 7, 6);


                // below padding and making borders for labels
                nov1.setPadding(new Insets(25,30,25,30) );
                nov1.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;" + "-fx-border-color: black;" + "-fx-background-color: grey;");
                nov2.setPadding(new Insets(25,30,25,30) );
                nov2.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;" + "-fx-border-color: black;" + "-fx-background-color: grey;");
                nov3.setPadding(new Insets(25,30,25,30) );
                nov3.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;" + "-fx-border-color: black;" + "-fx-background-color: grey;");
                nov4.setPadding(new Insets(25,30,25,30) );
                nov4.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;" + "-fx-border-color: black;" + "-fx-background-color: grey;");



            }


        }// end for loop to cycle through days of month 

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Label`s have a max size that matches the size required for the text and padding. The `GridPane` does not resize the `Label`s to a greater size which would be required for the 1-digit numbers to fill the column.

Simply setting the max size to infinity fixes this problem.

For not drawing double borders you could set the border size the top and right to 1 and bottom and left to 0, surround the `GridPane` with a border with bottom and left widths of 1 and top and right widths of 0 and wrap the grid in a `StackPane` for the padding:

```
private static final Insets LABEL_PADDING = new Insets(25, 30, 25, 30);

private static Label createLabel(String text) {
    Label label = new Label(text);
    label.setMaxSize(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    label.setPadding(LABEL_PADDING);
    return label;
}
```

```
// below makes S-M-T-W-T-F and green fill
for (int i = 0; i <= weekDays.length - 1; i++) {
    Label daysOfWeek = createLabel(weekDays[i]);
    grid.add(daysOfWeek, i, 0);
    daysOfWeek.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;"
            + "-fx-background-color: green;" + "-fx-border-color: black;" + "-fx-border-width: 1 1 0 0;");

}// end for loop to cycle through days of week

final String otherMonthStyle = "-fx-text-fill: white;-fx-border-color: black;-fx-background-color: grey;-fx-border-width: 1 1 0 0;";

//below are the days of the month 
for (int i = 1; i <= FRAMES; i++) {
    int yPos = ((i - 1) / 7) + 1;
    int xPos = (i - 1) % 7;

    if (i < 32) {
        Label monthDays = createLabel(String.valueOf(i));
        grid.add(monthDays, xPos, yPos);

        monthDays.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-border-width: 1 1 0 0;");

    } else if (i > 32) {
        // below creating november labels days 1 -- 4
        Label nov1 = createLabel("1");
        grid.add(nov1, 3, 5);
        Label nov2 = createLabel("2");
        grid.add(nov2, 4, 5);
        Label nov3 = createLabel("3");
        grid.add(nov3, 5, 5);
        Label nov4 = createLabel("4");
        grid.add(nov4, 6, 5);

        // below padding and making borders for labels
        nov1.setStyle(otherMonthStyle);
        nov2.setStyle(otherMonthStyle);
        nov3.setStyle(otherMonthStyle);
        nov4.setStyle(otherMonthStyle);
    }

}// end for loop to cycle through days of month 

grid.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;" + "-fx-border-width: 0 0 1 1;");

StackPane gridWrapper = new StackPane(grid);
gridWrapper.setPadding(new Insets(20));
```

Comment: Another trick (that I learned from a post on this forum) for the borders is to set an hgap and vgap on the grid pane and give it a background color (different to the labels). Then you see the background of the grid pane in the gaps, giving the effect of a border on each cell.

Comment: @fabian
Good sir, thank you so, so much. I have been on this for a while and your answer was thorough and incredibly clear. Thank you for the examples as well in improving my code to make it more efficient and beautiful. You are wonderful. 
James_D
Thank you for the innovative idea. I really like that! Will try it sometime. Thank you for your input.